# Set Value of Variable PHP from Function Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have a form where my customers must input some value at inputs.

my form is like this :

```
<form action="javascript:send();" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_main"><input type="number" name="quantidade" id="qt">
```

and i have a function called "send()" like this.

```
function send(arg1){


    if(typeof(arg1) === "undefined"){
        arg1 = 2
    }



    document.getElementById('qt').setAttribute('value',arg1);
```

below i have some ajax post and etc...

all my form is send by method post to this page : pacific_cbc_pr.php

where i have a variable like this.

```
$quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
```

the problem is that when someone for example input 100 or 200 at input quantidade .

the variable $quantidade must be "2" because i'm not passing parameter. but , the $quantidade is set with the value that the customer input.

someone could help me , because the variable $quantidade must be the value from :

document.getelementbyID....

EDIT : function send whole.

```
function send(arg1){
    if(typeof(arg1) === "undefined"){
        arg1 = 2
    }
    document.getElementById('qt').value = arg1;

        $("#warning_alerta").hide();
        $("#input_vazio").hide();
        $("#login_erro").hide();


        var formData = new FormData($('#form_principal')[0]);
        $("#loading").show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/pacific_cbc_pr.php",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                async:true,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(result){
                    if(result == 1)//logado
                    {
                        //$("#hide").show();
                        $('#text_modal').html('que');
                        $('#modal-container-188641').modal('show');
                    }
                    else if (result == 200)
                    {

                      $("#login_erro").show();

                    }
                    else if (result == 300)
                    {
                        $("#login_sucesso").show();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location = "index.php";},3000);
                    }
                    $("#loading").hide();
                }
            })

        },300);
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
function send(){
    document.getElementById("qt").value = 2;
}
```

BTW instead of doing this much you can simply pass custom data into your ajax post form.

do like below:-

```
function send(){

    $('#qt').val(2);//this is what you have to do

    $("#warning_alerta").hide();
    $("#input_vazio").hide();
    $("#login_erro").hide();
    $("#loading").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/pacific_cbc_pr.php",
            type: "post",
            data: $('#form_main').serializeArray(),
            cache: false,
            async:true,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result){
                if(result == 1)//logado
                {
                    //$("#hide").show();
                    $('#text_modal').html('que');
                    $('#modal-container-188641').modal('show');
                }else if (result == 200){
                    $("#login_erro").show();
                }else if (result == 300){
                    $("#login_sucesso").show();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location = "index.php";},3000);

                }
                $("#loading").hide();
            }
        });

    },300);
};
```

Comment: how for example ? using ajax post form

Comment: show your  ajax code through wich you are sending data of form. I will check and let you know

Comment: @Kamikaz0r  i hhad changed code a bit righr now. so check the latest edit and use it